# Extracted GeoJSON from TIFF

Tags: gdal, geojson, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

If there are a way to do

```
call("gdal_contour -i 10 -f GeoJSON".split(' ') + [file1, file2])
```

as Python call method of some library? Not via command line call and intermediate file storing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html) says "Functionality of this utility can be done from C with [GDALContourGenerate()](https://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#aceaf98ad40f159cbfb626988c054c085)."

A quick google turns up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100453/gdal-python-creating-contourlines) and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210500/calling-gdal-contour-from-python-ipython) with python solutions.