# How can I create contours from GeoTIFF and Python (GDAL, Rasterio, etc?) into shapefile with prj file

Tags: python, raster, gdal, shapefile, osgeo

I'm using a few reference StackExchange/Overflow posts here - and manual, but not coming up with what I'm after.

I have a GeoTIFF that I'm importing, and I need to develop out contours at regular intervals.

I've repurposed code from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210500/calling-gdal-contour-from-python-ipython), but the two issues I'm having are:
- I can't seem to specify regular intervals, rather I have to load my intervals manually into an array
- The shapefile is created without a prj file, meaning it's not spatially referenced.

My code so far:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
from numpy import *
from osgeo import ogr

#make contours from the raster
print('Making Contours')
indataset1 = gdal.Open(os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(sabre_out_dir)]) + 'mdROS.tif', GA_ReadOnly)
in1 = indataset1.GetRasterBand(1)
dst_filename = os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(sabre_out_dir)]) + 'mdROS_contour.shp'
ogr_ds = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile").CreateDataSource(dst_filename)
contour_shp = ogr_ds.CreateLayer('contour')

field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn("ID", ogr.OFTInteger)
contour_shp.CreateField(field_defn)
field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn("mdROS", ogr.OFTReal)
contour_shp.CreateField(field_defn)

#Generate Contourlines - Instead of manually specifying all intervals I'd like to say "every X interval"
gdal.ContourGenerate(in1, 0, 0, [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000,9000,10000], 0, 0, contour_shp, 0, 1)
ogr_ds.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining a spatial reference for the shapefile in your code. In order to do so, you have to specify it as the second argument when using the `CreateLayer()` method. For example, if your spatial reference would happen to be WGS84, you could write the following:

```py
from osgeo import osr

sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
contour_shp = ogr_ds.CreateLayer('contour', sr)
```

I guess you want the spatial reference to be the same as the raster, so you could do the following as well:

```py
from osgeo import osr

sr = osr.SpatialReference(indataset1.GetProjection())
contour_shp = ogr_ds.CreateLayer('contour', sr)
```

---

As for the intervals, I am not familiar with the `ContourGenerate()` function. However, you can easily create a list with intervals using Python's `range()` function by specifying a step as the third argument. For example:

```py
intervals = list(range(1000, 11000, 1000))  # start, end, step

print(intervals)
# [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]
```

Then, you can simply specify the intervals you just created as the argument.

```py
gdal.ContourGenerate(in1, 0, 0, intervals, 0, 0, contour_shp, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thankyou. The projection stuff was magic. I'll post another answer that shows how to do the intervals a bit better.

Comment: Also, your notes on how to use list and range are good. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I wound up going with.

The answer shows how to produce contours from a shapefile filled with polygons in a grid formation (think fishnet). The same approach should work for points, perhaps with a minimal amount of change.

Input can be shapefile or geopackage. Might work with other formats.

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
from osgeo import osr
from numpy import *
from osgeo import ogr

#mdROS is the field I'm wanting to work with from the original shp,
#so I have followed it all the way through the code. You could variablise this. 

# Make a raster using the shapefile - could go straight from dataframe
    print('Making Raster')
    input_geopackage = os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(out_dir)]) + 'input_file.shp'
    out_grid = make_geocube(
        vector_data=input_geopackage,
        resolution=(-30, 30 ),
    )
    out_grid["mdROS"].rio.to_raster(os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(out_dir)]) + 'mdROS.tif')

    #make contours from the raster
    print('Making Contours')
    indataset1 = gdal.Open(os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(out_dir)]) + 'mdROS.tif', GA_ReadOnly)
    sr = osr.SpatialReference(indataset1.GetProjection())
    in1 = indataset1.GetRasterBand(1)
    dst_filename = os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(out_dir)]) + 'mdROS_contour.shp'
    ogr_ds = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile").CreateDataSource(dst_filename)
    #contour_shp = ogr_ds.CreateLayer('contour') The line below outputs a spatially referenced shp
    contour_shp = ogr_ds.CreateLayer('contour', sr)

    field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn("ID", ogr.OFTInteger)
    contour_shp.CreateField(field_defn)
    field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn("mdROS", ogr.OFTReal)
    contour_shp.CreateField(field_defn)

    #Generate Contourlines - ContourGenerate from https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#ContourGenerate
    gdal.ContourGenerate(
        in1,    #Band srcBand
        500,      #double contourInterval - This defines contour intervals
        0,      #double contourBase
        [],      #int fixedLevelCount
        0,      #int useNoData
        0,      #double noDataValue
        contour_shp, #Layer dstLayer
        0,      #int idField
        1       #int elevField
        )
    #ogr_ds.Destroy() - Better not to use this method. See here: https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html
    #instead, empty and delete the dataframe
    ogr_ds = None
    del ogr_ds
```